# bash: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, bash, macos, terminal, sudo

I'm using Vs code on macos to create flutter projects for mobile application. A few days ago I installed postgresql since then vs code does not accept any command about flutter. When I try to open a new flutter application project, output gives this message:

```
[flutter_application_17] flutter create --template app --overwrite .
env: bash: No such file or directory
exit code 127
```

I tried to look at the paths in terminal but when I try to run any command like "bash, sudo" terminal gives `-bash: bash: command not found` message. When I try to run echo $PATH command it gives me this line:`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Users/macbookpro/development/flutter/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin:/Users/macbookpro/development/flutter/bin` 
so I export the line : `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"`by using `nano ~/.bash_profile` . Right after this commands I run `which bash` and it worked but when I close and reopen the terminal and rewrite the `which bash` command terminal gives "command not found" message.

I don't understand the exact problem so I can't find any solution for this problem. I would bu appreciated if someone solve this problem.

Comment: this https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html could help. I guess posgresql installation has changed PATH variable in one of the file that are sourced during login.

Comment: Are you sure that you have opened a bash **login** shell, after editing your profile? As the bash manpage tells you, `~/.bash_profile` is only processed by login shells, and even then only if it is not started with the `--noprofile` option. To help you further, you would need to post the command used by your Terminal to start a new shell.

Comment: Why is this tagged _sudo_? I don't see any reference to `sudo` in your question, but if you **do** use it, please specify how, because `sudo` also changes your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This error can mean that ./arm-mingw32ce-g++ doesn't exist (but it does), or that it exists and is a dynamically linked executable recognized by the kernel but whose dynamic loader is not available. You can see what dynamic loader is required by running ldd /arm-mingw32ce-g++; anything marked not found is the dynamic loader or a library that you need to install.

If you're trying to run a 32-bit binary on an amd64 installation:

Up to Ubuntu 11.04, install the package ia32-libs.
On Ubuntu 11.10, install ia32-libs-multiarch.
Starting with 12.04, install ia32-libs-multiarch, or select a reasonable set of :i386 packages in addition to the :amd64 packages.